# Warning from hyperref when loaded in elsarticle

Tags: hyperref, elsarticle

I use the class `elsarticle` to prepare my article to be submitted to Elsevier. In the past it works fine. Today I update my texlive and after that the warning from `hyperref` appears.
[image]
An example is

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter} 
\title{This is a paper}
\author[author1]{I'm here\corref{corresponding}}
\ead{mail@gmail.com}
\cortext[corresponding]{Corresponding author}
\address[author]{My school}
\begin{abstract}
test
\end{abstract}
\begin{keyword}
123
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}
\section{Introduction}
This is an Introduction.
\end{document}
```

Comment: The new version of elsarticle changed the definitions and added `\expandafter\gdef\csname Hy@author\endcsname{\useauthors}`  to the class. As using `\corref` inside `\author`  is a documented use they should also provide the suitable hyperref commands for this cases. So make a bug report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `hyperref` will try to write *everything* inside `\author` into the “author” field of the generated PDF file. According to your picture of the warning messages, it suggests that `elsarticle`’s special construction `\corref{corresponding}` cannot be written into the PDF.

A possible workaround is to redefine `\corref` to do nothing via the `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands` command (see, e.g., the example on Page 20 of the [`hyperref` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf)):

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \def\corref#1{}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{This is a paper}
\author[author1]{I'm here\corref{corresponding}}
\ead{mail@gmail.com}
\cortext[corresponding]{Corresponding author}
\address[author]{My school}
\begin{abstract}
test
\end{abstract}
\begin{keyword}
123
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}
\section{Introduction}
This is an Introduction.
\end{document}
```

But then you’ll have to do similar adjustments to `\tnoteref`, `\fnref` and who knows what else in `elsarticle`. I’d prefer specifying the title and authors in my PDF file myself.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  pdftitle={An awesome paper},
  pdfauthor={Alice, Bob, Charlie and Diana}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{This is a paper}
\author[author1]{I'm here\corref{corresponding}}
\ead{mail@gmail.com}
\cortext[corresponding]{Corresponding author}
\address[author]{My school}
\begin{abstract}
test
\end{abstract}
\begin{keyword}
123
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}
\section{Introduction}
This is an Introduction.
\end{document}
```

[image: PDF info]

---

**Added**: Those are *warning* messages after all, not *errors*. So I’d probably not even notice them (let alone be bothered to fix them) as long as my PDF is generated. :-)